# Crontab job that runs a command inside a docker container not working

Tags: cron, docker

In my todo list django website I have a command

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml exec todo-prod-web python manage.py do_something
```

that has to run in the prod enviroment everyday at 10 AM inside a docker container that is located in `home/ubuntu/prod/todo/docker-compose-prod.yml`, so I have to be in this directory to run the command.

When I SSH into the server and navigate to the directory and run it, it runs perfectly but when I run it as a `crontab` job it doesn't.

Here is how I tried to configure it:

1. I SSH into the server
2. I run

   ```
   sudo crontab -e
   ```
3. Ii added this in my `crontab` file:

   ```
   0 10 * * * cd home/ubuntu/prod/todo && docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml exec todo-prod-web python manage.py do_something
   ```
4. I saved the file

But it's not working. What should I do?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is far too vague to be useful.  what, exactly, do you mean by that?  Also: is cron installed and running? have you checked the cron logs? did cron mail you an error report? is the cron job in root's crontab or user ubuntu's crontab? if the latter, does user ubuntu have perm to run docker-compose like that without sudo?

Comment: i tried systemctl status cron i get running and active, i didn't check the logs but by doing sudo crontab -e and editing the file every command you put will run as root without need of sudo , i'm pretty sure that the problem is that i'm not running the command inside the specified directory , and yeah i need to check the logs for more details

Comment: Does the root user's home directory have a `home/ubuntu/prod/todo` directory that you can `cd` into? Or did you forget the initial `/` on that path? Also, is `docker-compose` in the `$PATH` in the cron environment or should you maybe update `PATH` in the crontab to contain the correct directories (alternatively, use `docker-compose` with its full absolute path)?